# Filter Custom Fields & Taxonomies Light not working o my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

[I've got Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuyBq.jpg)

This should result to have this on the link or omnibox.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stazU.png)

Comment: Try to add jquery in footer

Comment: How? what kind of jquery?